# No keyword with name 'foo' found error in robot framework

Tags: python, robotframework

Python: 3.7.3
Robot: 3.1.1

Robot framework is unable to read user defined python method.

**loo.robot**

```
*** Settings ***
Library             ../voo/boo/foo.py

fookeyword
  [Arguments]  ${arg1}  ${arg2}  ${arg3}
  ${body}=  body  ${arg1}  ${arg2}  ${arg3}
  [Return]  ${body}
```

**foo.py**

```
  class foo():
  def body(self,arg1,arg2,arg3):
      some operation
```

**File location:** **Robot**: Basefolder/roo/ioo.robot
               **Python**: Basefolder/voo/boo/foo.py

Note: All the above paths are being added in system environment variable, Pycharm interpreter and python path. Also, pycharm is able to navigate to respective python file and method while clicking but for some unknown reason, system still throwing 'No keyword with name 'body' found' error.

Can someone suggest what would be the cause of the above error?

Comment: The syntax of the first code block should be giving you errors. Either that or you've created a broken example. You can't define a keyword in the settings table. Also, the indentation of `foo.py` is broken. Please try to fix these problems in your example.

Comment: Are you getting an error when you import foo.py? That's usually the reason for not finding a keyword in a library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happened to me as well. The correct error message is not getting displayed, whenever a python function is called in robot framework.
The error should be in the python file. What you have to do is:
Make sure the python file is error free then try executing the robot script